# PHP incorrect access to static class member

Tags: php, static, phpunit

I have a class that has as a member variable a Mock instance of a static class, and when I try and reference the static methods I get a incorrect access to static class member:

```
class Foo {
    private my_static_class;

    public testmethod() {
        $this->my_static_class = mock_of_static_class;
        $this->my_static_class::static_method(); // Incorrect access to static class member 
    }
}
```

Using -> instead of :: doesn't seem to solve either, I end up with

```
Call to a member function static_method() on a non-object
```

Edit: the framework I am using returns the mock instance as a string

Comment: How are you creating the mock of your static class?

Comment: Using Box's Shmock framework. I found that the shmock is returned as a string only.

Comment: Can you post how you are creating your mock?  I don't think that things are happening exactly like you expect.  If the mock being returned is a string only, you should be getting parse errors rather than what you have happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the mock class as string only, create an instance of it.

```
$this->my_static_class = new $mock_of_static_class_as_string();
```

If you just want to call a static method, use [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
call_user_func(array($mock_of_static_class_as_string, 'static_method'));
```